# Convert Binary file to strings of 0s and 1s

Tags: python-3.x, file, binaryfiles

I have a binary `.dat` file from a random number generator which I need to convert to strings of `0`s and `1`s. I can't find an elegant solution for this in python.

The code that I have now. Need to convert `quantis.dat` as a string of `0`s and `1`s.

```
def bytesToBits(bytes):
  return bin(int(bytes.hex(), 16))

outfile = open("quantum.txt", "w")
infile = open("quantis.dat", "rb")
chunk = infile.read(1)
  
while chunk:
    decimal = bytesToBits(chunk) 
    outfile.write(decimal) 
    chunk = infile.read(1)

outfile.close()
```

Comment: Does your code generate any errors? Which one? Or generates what on output?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this for a list of strings:

```
>>> [f"{n:08b}" for n in open("random.dat", "rb").read()]
['01000001', '01100010', '01000010', '10011011', '01100111', ...
```

or if you want a single string:

```
>>> "".join(f"{n:08b}" for n in open("random.dat", "rb").read())
'010000010110001001000010100110110110011100010110101101010111011...
```

The `:08b` format specifier will format each byte as binary, having exactly 8 digits.

Comment: I want a single string of bits and save it into a .txt file. But I can't open the .txt document I've generated using your code. The .dat file is around 30 mb but the .txt file generated comes around 250 mb.

Comment: Yes, it will be exactly 8 times the size of your binary file as it's now 8 characters per byte. That is expected.

Comment: Read using what? You can certainly read the file using Python. If you are trying to open the `.txt` file in a text editor that might fail depending on the software you use, but what are you planning to do after opening a 250MB text file in a text editor anyway?